# Can't understand the error in DrRacket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to get a 3x3 chess board for the Four Knights problem. Here's the code in the racket language

```
 #lang racket
(define N 3)
(define nexts ; construct the graph
  (let ([ds (for*/list ([x 2] [x* '(+1 -1)] [y* '(+1 -1)])
              (cons (* x* (+ 1 x)) (* y* (- 2 x))))])
    (for*/vector ([i N] [j N])
      (filter values (for/list ([d ds])
                       (let ([i (+ i (car d))] [j (+ j (cdr d))])
                         (and (< -1 i N) (< -1 j N) (+ j (* N i)))))))))
(define (tour x y)
  (define xy (+ x (* N y)))
  (let loop ([seen (list xy)] [ns (vector-ref nexts xy)] [n (sub1 (* N N))])
    (if (zero? n) (reverse seen)
        (for/or ([next (sort (map (λ(n) (cons n (remq* seen (vector-ref nexts n)))) ns)
                             < #:key length #:cache-keys? #t)])
          (loop (cons (car next) seen) (cdr next) (sub1 n))))))
(define (draw tour)
  (define v (make-vector (* N N)))
  (for ([n tour] [i (in-naturals 1)]) (vector-set! v n i))
  (for ([i N])
    (displayln (string-join (for/list ([j (in-range i (* N N) N)])
                              (~a (vector-ref v j) #:width 2 #:align 'right))
                            " "))))
(draw (tour (random N) (random N)))
```

And it gives me this error `for: expected a sequence for n, got something else: #f` and highlights this section of my code:

```
(define (draw tour)
  (define v (make-vector (* N N)))
  (for ([n tour] [i (in-naturals 1)]) (vector-set! v n i))
  (for ([i N])
    (displayln (string-join (for/list ([j (in-range i (* N N) N)])
                              (~a (vector-ref v j) #:width 2 #:align 'right))
                            " "))))
```

And I'm not sure what the problem is. This is for class and I'm not experienced with the racket language. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error states that it expected the for clause `n` to be iterating over a sequence (list, string, vecor, range, lazy sequence) and not `#f` which is passed as a result from the `tour` procedure when there are no solutions.

The result of `tour` is the result of a `for/or` which will be `#f` (false) if none of the iterations ended with a result with the given start position. For `3x3` and `4x4` there are no solutions no matter the starting position and for `5x5` there are solutions, but not for all starting positions. Eg. Eg. if your random numbers pick `(1,2)` there are no solutions to that either. To fix this check if you found a solution and only draw when you have a solution:

```scm
(let* ((x (random N)) (y (random N)) (result (tour x y)))
  (if result
     (draw result) ; only draw when result is not #f
     (displayln (format "No results for initial position (~a,~a)" x y))))
```

My previous though was that `for` didn't take numbers was wrong. It will interpret it as `range` would and iterate `[0,N>`. The reason for my assumption is that this feature is nowhere to be found in the [for documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29).

```scm
(for/list ([n 10]) n) ; ==> (0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's supposed to have a first element since it's randomly being generated. If I change the N to any number above 4 it works, but not under, and I need it to work for 3

Comment: @butimnotarapper I've updated my answer. You wont find solutions for any starting position on 3x3 and 4x4 boards since there are none.